# What ways can I incorporate Java into my Node.js website?

Tags: java, web

I have an assignment which requires the use of Node.js, CSS, Pug/HTML, JavaScript, PostgreSQL and Java all in one project, however, I can't think of many interesting ways to incorporate Java into my website. My current idea is to simply program an Android application which will simply form a web browser for it. The project is a public bicycle rental site.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: java is for what android or server side?

Comment: Split your backend into 2 (or more) microservices, one in Java, one in Node. Maybe one manages inventory, the other manages the payments. Or you know, whatever arbitrary distinction you want to make.

Comment: Or go the opposite and quite ludicrous route and use Java applets somewhere (disclaimer: no, don't they are dead and should stay dead).

Comment: Or recognize that Node is used in the build process of most JavaScript SPAs.